# Question about a determiner

Tags: word-meaning, sentence-structure, determiners

> This sort of problem is quite common.
>
> This kind of exercise is very popular.

In the above sentences, the expressions *kind of* and *sort of* are used. I'm not sure whether those are **the subjects of the above verb** or **determiners**. When translated in the first language, those are regarded as determiners or adjective, but I haven't identified the category of determiner includes those in google.(also including *a variety of*) Also, I think those might be different according to some situations like [the example](https://%3Clink%3Ehttps://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/71548/these-kind-of-this-kind-of-those-kind-of). So, my question is what those serve as in the above sentences.

Comment: No, they're not determiners, but adverbs modifying the following verb or adjective. Note that determiners are dependents of nouns, not verbs or adjectives.

Comment: @BillJ Thanks!! you were right! I looked up those in a dictionary. Now, I change example sentences.

Comment: Now things are different, but they are still not determiners, and nor are they subjects. "Sort" and "kind" are nouns functioning as **heads** of the NPs "sort of problem" and "kind of exercise". The _of_ expressions are preposition phrases serving as **complement** of the head noun. Compare also "type of ...", which has a similar meaning. Note that the demonstrative "this" is a determiner in the NPs.

Comment: @BillJ there is a case that *a variety of* is various in *a variety of other devices* in my country's English site. Is it right? I think for other is determiner, *various other devices* is grammatically wrong.

Comment: @BillJ and why aren't they subjects of verbs? then, what are subjects in the above sentences? Is NPs subjects?

Comment: The subjects are the NPs "This sort of problem" and "this kind of exercise".

Comment: You are repeatedly changing your question. I've answered your questions about the class and function of "sort of " and "kind of".

Comment: @BillJ I just changed a little expressions for it looks suitable.I know. You provide a right explanation with me.

Comment: class ; an attractive quality or a high level of skill that is impressive. sort of ; to some extent but in a way that you cannot easily describe.

Comment: No, no, no! It means "class" as in 'word class' (or word category).

Comment: Partitive : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partitive

Answer (score 1):

> [*This* ***sort of** problem*] *is quite common*.
>
> [*This* ***kind of** exercise*] *is very popular*.

No: "sort of" and "kind of" not determiners. In fact they are not syntactic units at all, but just parts of ones.

The bracketed elements "this sort of problem" and "this kind of problem" are noun phrases functioning as subjects. They consist of the determiner "this" + "sort/kind" as head noun + "of problem/exercise" as preposition phrases functioning as complement of the head.

Comment: I have been confused about it for someone who is from my country wrote a determiner phrase with them in first language, not DP in English syntax.

Comment: I have still difficulties in quantifiers.

Comment: I asked a question. yet I didn't get any answer in *a variety of*. I think there are definitely  differences between NP and an adjective *various* in translation

Comment: @bak1936 "A variety of ..." is analysed the same way as your other examples, where the noun "variety" is head of the NP and the _of_ PP is its complement. "Various" is a marginal member of the determinative category. In "various items are missing", for example, "various" is a determiner.

Comment: In determinative category ; https://files.eric.ed.gov/fulltext/EJ1045117.pdf

Comment: You are right. I can verify it based on the above *link*, but I don't understand the entire context, even I don't know test methods. I should read slowly it when I have spare times. It is difficult for me. Anyway, Thanks!!

Comment: one more question! In DP, if there are two determiners, which of them is a head?

Comment: @bak1936 It is not possible to have two determiners in the same NP.

Comment: I have known there are pre-determiner, central-determiner and post-determiner. Seeing you did refer to the NP instead of the DP, Would I have to drop the DP in English?